# RhinoMock update method argument's properties

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks, stub

I have the following two lines in my code:

```
Factory.MyMethod(argument);
var property = argument.InterestingValue;
```

So, `MyMethod` takes in an instance of a class and updates the `InterestingValue` on this instance.  It doesn't return anything (void).

In my code I then use this `InterestingValue`.

For Unit testing, I want to create a stub of my Factory and program this so that when `MyMethod` is called, the actual object (argument) is updated.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
fakeFactory.Stub(ff=> ff.MyMethod(null)).IgnoreArguments()
            .WhenCalled(ff => 
            {
                var arg = (ArgumentClass)ssf.Arguments[0];
                arg.InterestingValue = new Whatever
                    {
                    };

                ff.ReturnValue = arg;
            });
```